# cannot reslove symbol 'android'

Tags: android, google-maps

I have written this code in my MapsActivity.java
In code android appears in red color and shows cannot resolve symbol 'android'.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Comment: Did you add the dependencies in your project?

Comment: @RakshitNawani what do you mean by dependencies? i didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be helpful.

1.) Choose File option from menu on left top side of android studio.

2.) Select the option : "Invalidate Cache/ Restart.." It will open an dialog.

3.) Click on the first button with option : "Invalidate and Restart"

4.) It will close the studio and restart it. Start indexing of the project.

It resolved my problem:

File -> Invalidate Cache/ Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Google Play services sdk.
In Android Studio, go to Tools->Android->Sdk Manager->Sdk Tools, then
select Google Play Services and hit apply, then rebuild your project.